# load CrossValidator model in Spark 2.2.1

Tags: pyspark, cross-validation, apache-spark-ml

I have Spark version 2.2.1 (cluster) and Spark 2.4 (my laptop). I can train and save a CrossValidator model in both the cluster and my laptop. But when I try to load it back, in Spark 2.4, CrossValidatorModel.load works but with Spark 2.2.1, CrossValidatorModel does not have a load method. How can I load it? Sample code is below: the data is from Spark [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt)

```
training = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt")
logreg = LogisticRegression(maxIter = 200)
paramGrid_logreg = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(logreg.regParam, np.linspace(0.0, 1, 11))\
                                     .addGrid(logreg.elasticNetParam, np.linspace(0, 1, 11)).build()
crossval_logreg = CrossValidator(estimator = logreg, 
                                  estimatorParamMaps = paramGrid_logreg, 
                                  evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(), numFolds = 10) 
cvModel_logreg = crossval_logreg.fit(training)
cvModel_logreg.save("cvModel_logreg_numFolds10")
```

now, with spark 2.4, I can load it using:

```
CrossValidatorModel.load('cvModel_logreg_numFolds10')
```

But in Spark 2.2 CrossValidatorModel does have load method. Any way to read it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think you can't. I have also faced the same problem, finally I switched to spark 2.3 which contains the load function.